# how to turn text into a dictionary list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a text with the content shown below.
This is a string.

```
{'tempo': 99000, 'lider': 0, 'visao': 1}, {'tempo': 99000, 'lider': 1, 'visao': 0}
```

If possible, I would like someone to help me build a list of dictionaries with this information.
It looks like this:

```
list = [{'tempo': 99000, 'lider': 0, 'visao': 1}, {'tempo': 99000, 'lider': 1, 'visao': 0}]
```

Best wishes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple with ast module, use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

>>> astr = "{'tempo': 99000, 'lider': 0, 'visao': 1}, {'tempo': 99000, 'lider': 1, 'visao': 0}"
>>> list(ast.literal_eval(astr))
[{'tempo': 99000, 'lider': 0, 'visao': 1}, {'tempo': 99000, 'lider': 1, 'visao': 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to split the string, and json.loads to convert each element of the resulting list into a dict:

```
import re
import json

s = "{'tempo': 99000, 'lider': 0, 'visao': 1}, {'tempo': 99000, 'lider': 1, 'visao': 0}"

#json.loads expects double quotes, so replace single with double
s = s.replace("'", '"')  

# regex pattern to match ", " between } and { characters
pattern = "(?<={)*, (?={)"  

# split string based on regex pattern, parse each element to a dict with json.loads 
d = [json.loads(d) for d in re.split(pattern, s)]  
print(d)
```